# Pandoc `writeMarkdown` does not include metadata, i.e. write (read a) is not a - what extension is required?

Tags: pandoc

I want to creat an utilty to transform some text in a markdown file and want to procude a new markdown file. The metadata is not changed.

The operations read and write should be inverse (or at least idempotent), but I cannot find a way to have pandoc reproduce the input file including the metadata. What combination of `Extensions` and `Options` are required?

Here my minimal working example with the newest pandoc from `lst-15.13`.

```
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Module      :   a test for pandoc output of yaml
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}

module Main     where     

import qualified Data.Text                as T
import Text.Pandoc 
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO )   

main :: IO ()
main =  do 
    putStrLns $ ["input", showT inputMd]
    res <-  sub inputMd 
    case res of 
        Left st -> putStrLns $ ["error", show st]
        Right q -> 
            do 
                putStrLns $ ["result q\n",  showT $ q]
                putStrLns $ ["should be the same as input p\n",  showT inputMd]
                putStrLns $ ["same", show (inputMd == ( q))]
                return () 
    return () 

showT = show . T.unpack 
putStrLns = putStrLn . unwords

sub :: T.Text -> IO (Either PandocError T.Text)
sub input1 = do 
        res <- runIO $ 
            do 
                let readOptions = def{readerStandalone = True  
                                        ,  readerExtensions = extensionsFromList 
                                                [Ext_yaml_metadata_block ] 
                                        }               
                p   <- readMarkdown readOptions ( input1)
                        -- def does not analyse metadata
                        -- readOptions analysis metadata 
                        -- output is then only the markdown 

                -- t1 :: String <- liftIO $readFile "/home/frank/Workspace8/pandocTest/temp.tpl"
                -- t2 <- compileDefaultTemplate (T.pack t1)
                let writeOptions =  def {writerSetextHeaders = False
                                        , writerExtensions = extensionsFromList 
                                                [Ext_yaml_metadata_block] 
                                        -- ,  writerTemplate = Just t2                                                 
                                        }             
                q   <- writeMarkdown writeOptions p
                        -- def gives only the markdown part 
                        -- but not including the titel
                liftIO $ putStrLns  ["AST \n", show p]
                return q
        res2 <- handleError res
        return res

inputMd = T.unlines ["---"
        ,"title: The Future of AA"
        ,"..."
        ,""
        ,"## second level"
        ,"text for nothing"
        ] ::  T.Text
```

The use of a template comiles but gives a runtime error:

```
Could not find data file /home/frank/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/668b320207ef95ba5255b2b20895a7f7315ff61076bb3ab82e76f7ef56076320/8.8.3/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.8.3/pandoc-2.9.1.1/data/templates/default.

$if(titleblock)$ $titleblock$
```

Comment: not to discourage you, but perhaps you'd be better served writing a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html)?

Comment: Use [`compileTemplate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.9.2.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Templates.html#v:compileTemplate) instead of `compileDefaultTemplate`.

Comment: @mb21 thank you for the suggestion. What I want has exactly the function of a filter (which I did not realize) and I can simplify my code. Will try!

Comment: @tarleb: then I do not understand what the argument for `compileDefaultTemplate` is good for. I looked at the source and cannot figure it out. But definitely, I should have used `compileTemplate` - will try a bit later today! Thank you!

Comment: @tarleb: it works with a compiled template, which is the same as the default template. This I did not expect! any explanation?

Comment: @mb21 I tried to construct a filter, but it creates problems with metadata. I have started a new question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62060820/pandoc-filter-does-not-read-metadata-not-a-valid-json-value. Thank you for your suggestion - it seems the more direct route!

Comment: it worked nearly with the template from https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.markdown but added a space in front. I had to remove the space between the $if...$no space her!$...$ in the template. I still do not understand why it worked with this temlate (which I assume is the default template) and not with compiling with the default template? Anyhow, thank you for the help.

Comment: @user855443 The argument to `compileDefaultTemplate` gives the name of the output format. So with `compileDefaultTemplate "html5"`, one gets the template which pandoc uses when called with `--standalone --to=html5`.

Comment: @user855443 I think what happened with the extra space is that GitHub interprets the template sources as Markdown (due to the file extension), thus converting newlines into spaces. GitHub doesn't know that the template should not be treated as normal Markdown. Clicking on the `Raw` button  gives the actual source code.

Comment: another trick learned. thank you for the help!