# pandoc filter does not read metadata - not a valid json value

Tags: pandoc

The filter copied from https://pandoc.org/filters.html and run with

```
pandoc -f markdown  -t markdown  --filter filterUmlaut -o test1.md coronatest.md
```

produces the error

```
Failed reading: not a valid json value at 'input---ntitle:TheFutureofAAn...nn##secondlevelntextfornothingn'
```

which is the metadata at the beginning of `coronatest.md`. The file can be run with the same command without the filter option:

```
pandoc -f markdown  -t markdown   -o test1.md coronatest.md
```

What do I miss?

Comment: not sure which filter you copied... but if you don't know Haskell, probably easier to get started with a [lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)...

Comment: i think I had a confusion in the stack build process - nothing to do with the example filter. I voted to delete, because nothing useful came of it. thank you for the suggestion to use filer, which after more experimenting, I found difficult for my use case: the filter would require to read in data (think of it as a spell checker with a dictionary.  I do not see how to do it with a filter. Suggestions are welcome!